# Average of Array Values by Position from a set of documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I recently wrote a question which I have tried out but it has resulted in a different problem. [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932287/sum-array-number-values-across-multiple-documents/49932466?noredirect=1#comment86880980_49932466) and @NeilLunn helped me with working through the problem.

The script he created and I then modified for my use is below:

```
db.getCollection('widget_documents').aggregate([
{ "$unwind": { "path": "$graph_data", "includeArrayIndex": "index" } },
{ "$group": {
"_id": {
  "group": "$displayname",
  "index": "$index"
},
"graph_data": { "$avg": "$graph_data.value" }
}},
{ "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
{ "$group": {
  "_id": "$_id.group",
  "graph_data": { "$push": "$graph_data" }
}},
{ "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }  
])
```

It is supposed to unwind an array and then create the average of each of the comma separated values and keeping their same position. However, the values are all null which I cannot work out how to fix. See below results:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : "Accommodation & Functions",
"graph_data" : [
    null,
    null
]
},

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : "Agriculture & Forestry",
"graph_data" : [
    null,
    null
]
},

/* 3 */
{
"_id" : "Business & Professional Services",
"graph_data" : [
    null,
    null
]
}
```

I include an exert of the data set being used for this aggregation. The result I want is two averaged values. I also want to include a field which has the count of documents in each group.

```
/* 1 createdAt:20/04/2018, 16:12:27*/
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ad968ab72f71f12a8298435"),
"object_class" : "De-normalised Datapoint",
"object_type" : "website-traffic",
"object_creation_date" : ISODate("2016-10-25T13:37:33.173+13:00"),
"party_uuid" : "b92ffd39-4382-4c48-86a5-3fe5f36aaa70",
"subscription_uuid" : "4f6731ca-0e1e-4808-91f8-8aa46f2f27ec",
"profile_id" : "8198633",
"extras" : [
    {
        "label_key" : "d.3",
        "value_1" : 43,
        "value_2" : 519743
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.4",
        "value_1" : 25,
        "value_2" : 236700
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.5",
        "value_1" : 33,
        "value_2" : 134790
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.6",
        "value_1" : 12,
        "value_2" : 0
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.7",
        "value_1" : 10,
        "value_2" : 2407250
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.1",
        "value_1" : 32,
        "value_2" : 54143
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.2",
        "value_1" : 35,
        "value_2" : 224333
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.3",
        "value_1" : 33,
        "value_2" : 70071
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.4",
        "value_1" : 28,
        "value_2" : 505857
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.5",
        "value_1" : 19,
        "value_2" : 11941
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.6",
        "value_1" : 9,
        "value_2" : 205000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.7",
        "value_1" : 12,
        "value_2" : 21400
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.1",
        "value_1" : 25,
        "value_2" : 4600
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.2",
        "value_1" : 1,
        "value_2" : 10000
    }
],
"graph_data" : [
    {
        "data_set_name" : "unique.visits",
        "value" : [
            35,
            20,
            31,
            11,
            8,
            28,
            30,
            26,
            21,
            17,
            8,
            7,
            20,
            0
        ]
    },
    {
        "data_set_name" : "repeat.visits",
        "value" : [
            8,
            5,
            2,
            1,
            2,
            4,
            5,
            7,
            7,
            2,
            1,
            5,
            5,
            1
        ]
    }
],
"displayname" : "Accommodation & Functions"
},

/* 2 createdAt:20/04/2018, 16:12:27*/
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ad968ab72f71f12a8298436"),
"object_class" : "De-normalised Datapoint",
"object_type" : "website-traffic",
"object_creation_date" : ISODate("2016-10-06T11:53:58.960+13:00"),
"party_uuid" : "f5b3ca48-52c3-4f3d-b84f-8240e0a4b844",
"subscription_uuid" : "fbfe4f05-3eba-4db5-822c-6996cec71683",
"profile_id" : "71567572",
"extras" : [
    {
        "label_key" : "d.4",
        "value_1" : 212,
        "value_2" : 534000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.5",
        "value_1" : 246,
        "value_2" : 220000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.6",
        "value_1" : 60,
        "value_2" : 179000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.7",
        "value_1" : 36,
        "value_2" : 344000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.1",
        "value_1" : 152,
        "value_2" : 332000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.2",
        "value_1" : 227,
        "value_2" : 426000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.3",
        "value_1" : 314,
        "value_2" : 434000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.4",
        "value_1" : 223,
        "value_2" : 389000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.5",
        "value_1" : 268,
        "value_2" : 269000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.6",
        "value_1" : 145,
        "value_2" : 261000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.7",
        "value_1" : 39,
        "value_2" : 202000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.1",
        "value_1" : 245,
        "value_2" : 336000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.2",
        "value_1" : 203,
        "value_2" : 180000
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.3",
        "value_1" : 174,
        "value_2" : 223000
    }
],
"graph_data" : [
    {
        "data_set_name" : "unique.visits",
        "value" : [
            93,
            184,
            27,
            23,
            92,
            95,
            187,
            125,
            174,
            110,
            24,
            137,
            110,
            111
        ]
    },
    {
        "data_set_name" : "repeat.visits",
        "value" : [
            119,
            62,
            33,
            13,
            60,
            132,
            127,
            98,
            94,
            35,
            15,
            108,
            93,
            63
        ]
    }
],
"displayname" : "Retail & Shopping"
},

/* 3 createdAt:20/04/2018, 16:12:27*/
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ad968ab72f71f12a8298437"),
"object_class" : "De-normalised Datapoint",
"object_type" : "website-traffic",
"object_creation_date" : ISODate("2016-11-14T17:29:30.155+13:00"),
"party_uuid" : "b79eebdb-0bab-45c7-b6ef-1faec1c1c3bb",
"subscription_uuid" : "865768db-49de-4cc9-86f5-960de932e589",
"profile_id" : "71567572",
"extras" : [
    {
        "label_key" : "d.2",
        "value_1" : 163,
        "value_2" : 219024
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.3",
        "value_1" : 261,
        "value_2" : 335845
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.4",
        "value_1" : 224,
        "value_2" : 506752
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.5",
        "value_1" : 292,
        "value_2" : 459927
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.6",
        "value_1" : 222,
        "value_2" : 100621
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.7",
        "value_1" : 127,
        "value_2" : 141699
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.1",
        "value_1" : 256,
        "value_2" : 568735
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.2",
        "value_1" : 396,
        "value_2" : 354892
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.3",
        "value_1" : 388,
        "value_2" : 481027
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.4",
        "value_1" : 375,
        "value_2" : 612040
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.5",
        "value_1" : 247,
        "value_2" : 186809
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.6",
        "value_1" : 372,
        "value_2" : 91135
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.7",
        "value_1" : 272,
        "value_2" : 123998
    },
    {
        "label_key" : "d.1",
        "value_1" : 284,
        "value_2" : 525792
    }
],
"graph_data" : [
    {
        "data_set_name" : "unique.visits",
        "value" : [
            108,
            206,
            146,
            199,
            190,
            110,
            189,
            323,
            309,
            298,
            184,
            350,
            259,
            233
        ]
    },
    {
        "data_set_name" : "repeat.visits",
        "value" : [
            55,
            55,
            78,
            93,
            32,
            17,
            67,
            73,
            79,
            77,
            63,
            22,
            13,
            51
        ]
    }
],
"displayname" : "Cafes, Restaurants, Hotels & Food"
}
```

It isn't the complete set but you'll get the idea. Thanks for all your help on this, much appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing called `"value"` therefore the result is `null`. There all `"value_1"` and `"value_2"`.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn scroll down to the array called graph_data

Comment: Sorry I see it now. You're missing an `$unwind`. Array within array you know.

Comment: ah - just done it! thanks - one last thing. You'll notice there are two sets of data in the graph_data array. I guess I need to group by graph_data.data_set_name as well and include the data_set_name in each document. I've tried adding it to the group but it caused an error. Does my method seem correct? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you seem to missing an `$unwind` in the interpretation as there is "arrays within arrays". Therefore that would instead be:

```
db.getCollection('widget_documents').aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$graph_data" },
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$graph_data.value", "includeArrayIndex": "index" } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "group": "$displayname",
      "index": "$index"
    },
    "graph_data": { "$avg": "$graph_data.value" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.group",
    "graph_data": { "$push": "$graph_data" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }  
])
```

Or if you actually wanted to the "inner" `"data_set_name"` of each array entry, then you want something like:

```
db.getCollection('widget_documents').aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$graph_data" },
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$graph_data.value", "includeArrayIndex": "index" } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "group": {
        "displayname": "$displayname",
        "data_set": "$graph_data.data_set_name"
      },
      "index": "$index"
    },
    "graph_data": { "$avg": "$graph_data.value" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.group",
    "graph_data": { "$push": "$graph_data" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }  
])
```

Either of those is keeping the array "averages" per position across the documents they actually "group", if any. In your sample, this would just be per document as each has unique "displayname" values.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn that is exactly it, I used the second one was perfect, much appreciated, again